# SQL テーブル上の2つのそれぞれの値を、1つのテーブルから参照する効率的な方法

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

SQLのJOINの方法で、効率的な方法を探しています。
言葉で説明するのが難しく・・・テーブルで説明します
（環境はBigQuery standardSQLです)

## table_A

| ID | name | departure | arrival |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | sato | 100 | 200 |
| 2 | suzuki | 200 | 300 |
| 3 | tanaka | 300 | 200 |

## table_B

| ID | spot |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | tokyo |
| 200 | osaka |
| 300 | nagoya |

## 実現したい結果

| name | departure | arrival |
| --- | --- | --- |
| sato | tokyo | osaka |
| suzuki | osaka | nagoya |
| tanaka | nagoya | osaka |

これを実現するには、例えば

```
WITH 
dep_spot AS
(
 SELECT
  departure,
  spot
 FROM
  table_A as a
 JOIN
  table_B as b
 ON
  a.departure = b.ID
),
ari_spot AS
(
 SELECT
  arrival,
  spot
 FROM
  table_A as a
 JOIN
  table_B as b
 ON
  a.arrival = b.ID
)
SELECT
　name,
　dep_spot.spot as departure,
　ari_spot.spot as arrival
FROM
　table_A
JOIN
　dep_spot USING(departure)
AND ari_spot USING(departure)
```

といった形でそれぞれを参照するwith句をつくるしかないのかなあ、と思いつつ、大きなデータだと意図せぬ結果になるようなことがあり、そもそもやり方がおかしいのか？と思っている次第です。
こうしたケースの良い知恵をお貸しください。

Comment: ここでいう効率的とは何ですか？メモリやCPUのリソースの消費が少ない？実行時間が短い？

Comment: 実行時間と、コードの長さです。そもそもBQだとデータによっては4〜5分かかったりして、そもそも冗長な書き方になっているのでは？と思いました

Comment: 通常のDBMSとSQLであれば、table_Aにtable_Bを２回JOINするだけだと思いますが（実行効率はオプティマイザが最適化する）、そのやり方がわからないのか、google-bigquery特有の問題でそうできないのかどちらでしょう？

Comment: table_Aにtable_Bを２回JOINするというのがわかりません・・・当方の示したコードでなく別のやり方であれば例を示していただけるとありがたいです

Answer (score 0, accepted):

一般的なSQLで書くならこんな感じだと思います

```
SELECT 
    name,
    dep.spot departure, 
    arr.spot arrival
FROM 
    table_A
JOIN   
    table_B dep
ON  
    table_A.departure = dep.ID
JOIN   
    table_B arr
ON  
    table_A.arrivalint = arr.ID
;
```

実行効率については、table_A.IDとtable_B.IDに（ユニーク）インデックスを付加することになると思いますが
それらが主キーであれば、大概のDBMSで自動的にインデックス化されてると思います。

一般的なDBMSの実行については、オプティマイザが判断して最良と思われるものを選択してくれることになっています。
理想的には同じ結果なら同じ最適な実行計画で実行してほしいのですが、複雑なSQLではなかなかそういかないのが実情です。
もとのSQLよりこのSQLのほうが良い実行計画で実行される期待度が高いと思います。

これ以上の実行効率を求めるのであれば、実際のテーブル定義と行数で、使っているDBMSごとの特性を考慮したチューニングが必要になります。
google-bigqueryについては私は詳しくないのでこれ以上の回答はできません